# How to avoid line breaks within chemical formulas using FPDF?

Tags: php, fpdf, line-breaks

I generate PDF documents from text using FPDF. The documents often contain chemical formulas, so I extended the FPDF class for subscript support:

```php
<?php
require('fpdf182/fpdf.php');

class PDF extends FPDF
{
    protected $subFontSizeold;

    function __construct($orientation = 'P', $unit = 'mm', $format = 'A4')
    {
        //Call parent constructor
        parent::__construct($orientation, $unit, $format);
        //Initialization
        $this->subFontSizeold = $this->FontSizePt;
    }

    function WriteSub($txt)
    {
        $this->subFontSizeold = $this->FontSizePt;
        $this->SetFontSize(7);
        $subOffset = (((7 - $this->subFontSizeold) / $this->k) * 0.3) + (-2 / $this->k);
        $this->SetXY($this->x,  $this->y - $subOffset);

        $this->Write(5, $txt, '', 1);
        $subOffset = (((7 - $this->subFontSizeold) / $this->k) * 0.3) + (-2 / $this->k);
        $this->SetXY($this->x,  $this->y + $subOffset);
        $this->SetFontSize($this->subFontSizeold);
    }
}

// here starts the MWE:

$pdf = new PDF();
$pdf->SetMargins(23, 30);
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Helvetica', '', 10);
$pdf->Write(6, "Dissolve all compounds except yeast extract and Casamino acids, adjust pH to 4.0 - 4.2 with 10 N ");
$pdf->Write(6, "H", "", 1);
$pdf->WriteSub("2");
$pdf->Write(6, "SO", "", 1);
$pdf->WriteSub("4");
$pdf->Write(6, " at room temperature and autoclave. Prior to inoculation add yeast extract and Casamino acids from stock solutions sterilized by filtration.");

$pdf->Output();

?>
```

This is how the resulting PDF looks like:

[image: Unwanted line break within chemical formula]

As you can see, the subscripts are displayed correctly, but when the formula is at the end of an line, a subscript can cause an unwanted line break.
I already tried to avoid this behaviour by setting `$no_ln=1` (4th argument of `Write()`), which causes the line break in my example to appear after H<sub>2</sub>S instead of H<sub>2</sub>.

**Question**: Any idea on how to prevent a line break within the formula? Why is the `$no_ln` argument not working as I would expect?

Comment: Have you tried replacing the spaces with non-breaking spaces?

Comment: `Write()` has only 3 arguments.

Comment: Just before you write the formula, you should check if there is enough space left on the line. If not, do a line break.